# Rails devise how to display the last user signed in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using devise in my rails application.
I want to display the last user that is logged in, not the current user but the last user.
How can it do?

Answer (score 1):

With mongoid it's:

```
User.all.desc(:last_sign_in_at).limit(2).last
```

In AR it's probably something like:

```
User.all(:order => 'last_sign_in_at DESC', :limit=>2).at(1)
```

Comment: User.first(:order => "last_sign_in_at DESC") gives the first user logged in, while User.last(:order => "last_sign_in_at DESC") gives the current_user, I want the user that has logged in before the current user.

Comment: You're right, use User.all(:order => 'last_sign_in_at DESC', :limit=>2).at(1)

Comment: It doesn't work if: user-1 sign in, then user-2 sign in so the last signed in is user-1. After user-2 log out then re-signed in. Now the last user signed in should be user-2, but with User.all(:order => 'last_sign_in_at DESC', :limit=>2).at(1) the last signed in user displayed is still user-1.